# Asynch fetch in For-loop - access to result (finished) variable

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous

I'm new to JS asynchronous and I have a question about: how to start working on created array only if all queries are done. I fetch pages in for loop. That's my code:

```html
var allOrgReposData = [];
var repoContributorsUrls = [];
for (var i=1; i <= orgPageIterations; i++) {
  var orgReposUrl = 'https://api.github.com/orgs/angular/repos?page='+i;
  fetch(orgReposUrl)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(orgReposData => {
    allOrgReposData = allOrgReposData.concat(orgReposData);
    console.log(allOrgReposData);
   })
}
```

As You can see the allOrgReposData array is created on for loop, but If I try to do something on this array, script do It on every iteration so my operations are multipicated instead execution single time for exapmle (30 item on page): 30; 60; 90; 120; 150; 171 = 621 instead 171.

Is It possible to "wait" for finish fetching and get access to array without this. "multiplication"?

Greetings!

Comment: you can try async and await. Maybe it will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Promise.all` which will wait until all promises are complete:

```js
var allOrgReposData = [];
var repoContributorsUrls = [];

var promises = [];
let orgPageIterations = 1;

for (var i = 1; i <= orgPageIterations; i++) {
  let orgReposUrl = 'https://api.github.com/orgs/angular/repos?page=' + i;
  promises.push(fetch(orgReposUrl).then(response => response.json()));
}

Promise.all(promises)
  .then(data => {
    allOrgReposData = data;
    console.log(allOrgReposData);
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Please note that I've also changed `var orgReposUrl` to `let orgReposUrl` to make us of block scoping.

Comment: What if I've got error Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: response.json is not a function - Note! I use isomorphic-fetch library

Comment: Ah, okay, thats because response is now an array. Try and change it to `response.map((r) => r.json());`

Comment: It seems the response is now treated as array but Error is: 'response' is not defined

Comment: Yes, It's working, but I've got a Array of Arrays [Array(30), Array(30), Array(30), Array(30), Array(30), Array(21)] I think I can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep track of the number of calls you did with a variable :

```
var allOrgReposData = [];
var repoContributorsUrls = [];
var callSuccess = 1; //Variable keeping track of your ajax calls
for (var i=1; i <= orgPageIterations; i++) {
  var orgReposUrl = 'https://api.github.com/orgs/angular/repos?page='+i;
  fetch(orgReposUrl)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(orgReposData => {
    allOrgReposData = allOrgReposData.concat(orgReposData);
    console.log(allOrgReposData);
    callSuccess++; //Increment your var for each call

    if(callSuccess == orgPageIterations){ //If every call has already been made, then continue
      //DO YOUR THING HERE
    }
   })
}
```